# Create a new file on sd card everytime

Tags: android, file, sd-card

How to create a new file file every time in android.

when my file gets created and i want to add the contents on it , But what is happening -its  open an existing file and appends the content on it .

I want to create a new file every time with having a new content on it .

```
String filenamedir="BGActivityMeasurement";
    String filename="Abc.txt";
    File file =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),filenamedir);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.mkdir();
    }

            File ecgfile=new File(file,filename);


        try {
            FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(ecgfile,true);
            filewriter.append(data);
            filewriter.flush();
            filewriter.close();
            Log.i("FilePath", "saving data into file");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Just think over it ..I 'm trying to create new file directory inside If condition ,and the condition checking  every times if file with the given file name is exist or not ? you just change your file name differ from existing one ,each and every time when ever you want to store your new content . For the best practices create file name as per the date time ,so it will never conflicts .

Comment: i already did it ,but i have some condition so i have to read the file also, if i set the file name according to current timestamp, i want be able to read the specific file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`

The second argument asks whether you want to append to the file. You pass in `true` when you really want `false`.

What you really want is this:

```
FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(ecgfile,false);
```

Comment: @abh22ishek No problem, it happens to the best of us. If this answer has solved your problem please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark located underneath the downvote button.